# Need to rewrite sql query

Tags: sql

I am new to query and I need help writing a query.

I want to Select

```
Project_Post.ProjectPost 
from Project_Post 
Where Project_Post.ProfileId = (User_profile.ProfileID Where User_profile.UserId = @username)
And Project_Post.Project date is less than Project_Follower.LastPageView 
Where Project_Follower.profileId = (User_profile.ProfileID Where User_profile.UserId = @username)
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's very hard to read your "query". Please format properly!

Comment: @jarlh its not the query, its just an explanation of what i want to retrieve Thanks.

Comment: I understand, but still a bit hard to read... Give us table definitions, sample data and wanted result!

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like that:

```
SELECT col1, col2 -- specify what you need
FROM Project_Post pp
INNER JOIN User_profile up ON up.ProfileId = pp.ProfileId
INNER JOIN Project_Follower pf ON pf.profileId = up.ProfileID 
WHERE
pp.Project_date < pf.LastPageView AND  
pp.ProfileId = (
                  SELECT ProfileID 
                  FROM User_profile 
                  WHERE UserId = @username
               )  AND
pf.profileId = (
                  SELECT ProfileID 
                  FROM User_profile 
                  WHERE UserId = @username
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you give us the structure of tables, but depend on your query, this something like :

```
SELECT pp.ProjectPost 
FROM Project_Post AS pp WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN User_Profile AS up WITH(NOLOCK) ON pp.ProfileID = up.ProfileID
    INNER JOIN Project_Follower AS pf WITH(NOLOCK) ON pp.ProfileID = pf.ProfileID
WHERE up.Username = @Username
    AND pp.Project_Date < pf.LastPageView
```